# How can I implement smooth scrolling using Locomotive Scroll?

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling, locomotive-scroll

I created a portfolio using a tutorial on Locomotive Scroll, and then I added a button using JavaScript to go to the top of the page; however, the button does not work.

### How can I implement smooth scrolling while using Locomotive Scroll?

I have already tried using `scroll.stopPropagation()` at the bottom of Locomotive Scroll.

Comment: Was an error thrown in the console? If so, could you share it please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.